# How to reset my movement speed, after messing around in the console?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

So, I was messing around in the Skyrim console and increased my speed a lot. Now I want to reset my speed but the command `player.setav speedmult 100` isn't working. Is there any way to reset this?

Comment: player.setav speedmult 100 sets your speed to 100%, so perhaps it's trying to set your speed to 100% of your current speed instead of original speed?

Comment: Thought of that as well, so I tried to set it to 1 (%). No change.

Comment: You might be able to fix it with an .ini file tweak. I'll check once I get home.

Comment: Does this question need the "mods" tag if it doesn't involve external mods?

Comment: I didn't set that. Someone must have edited the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it out myself :) After browsing the console's help, I found the command `forceav`, this works.

`player.forceav speedmult 100`

Comment: it doesnt work for me:( pc version...
do i have to wait a while ?
im running like crazy, cannot play like this :( please help :)

Comment: autoruns also...

Comment: Try either one of `player.setav speedmult 100` , `player.modav speedmult 100` or `player.forceav speedmult 100`. And press Alt to run: Else it won't change at all.

Comment: i loaded a different save, seems ok now, thx for help :)

Comment: i tried the forceav but it doesnt work....

Answer (score 6):

The `setav` command *adds* the integer to the player's current skill level. 
the `forceav` command sets the skill level to the specified integer.